# AWS SES - Design on how to save incoming email into database (SQL Server)

Tags: .net, sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

AWS SES - Design on how to save incoming emails into database (SQL Server). Focus is more on text content rather than attachments.

Has any one implemented it end to end and can share some useful code or design?

Platform we are using - .NET with SQLServer.

Comment: Perhaps you may get more help if you let people know what your code base is? Is this a web app? Are you using a framework? PHP, node, .Net? I believe this will go a long way to finding the help you need.

Comment: Thanks @Azeame , I have added it above now (.NET with SQL Server)

Comment: good luck unfortunately I'm not familiar with .NET

Comment: Thanks @Azeame for your reply, I'm more after the design aspect, like using SNS/Lambda service. I hope some one has done it end to end who may shed some light on this.